# multiple AJAX responses

Tags: php, ajax, jquery

I'm making a ajax request to a page that does some expensive operations (re-indexing some  database tables).
These take time, and I want to display progress messages until it finishes.

How can I do that? Is this possible? Because the javascript waits until the page has finished loading then displays all the messages...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Return one message per request. Keep making AJAX requests until a specific "done" response is received. This is how push or "[COMET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29)" works behind the scenes, you could use a proper push technology, too.

The hidden/implied point here is you shouldn't be doing expensive operations on page scripts.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution would be to keep polling on a variable that you use as a flag in the database such thy when that expensive operation has completed, it will set that flag you're polling on. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I'd nest a loading div inside your main content div.  Set the background-image to an AJAX loader (which you can download [here](http://preloaders.net/)).  When you click whatever button you specify, the loading div will show and your main content will have an extra CSS selector name.  You can make the opacity 0.5 or whatever you want for .main-content.loading.  Here's the jQuery:

```
$(".button").click(function(){
   $(".main-content").addClass(".loading");
   $(".main-content .loader").show();
   $.ajax({
      data: //whatever data,
      type: "POST",
      url: // whatever url,
      success: function(d){
        $(".main-content").removeClass(".loading");
        $(".main-content .loader").hide();
        $(".enter-content").html(d);
      }
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

jquery ui has a pretty nice progress bar with examples of how to use it: http://jqueryui.com/demos/progressbar/